# what payment gateway do you use on your Magento 2 CE?

Tags: payment

We recently migrated from Magento 1.9.3.8 to Magento 2.2.7. We were using CyberSource as the payment gateway when we were using Magento 1. Right now our team is looking at the payment gateway again to see if we have any other options. I am not saying CyberSource is good or bad, I am just simply looking for other options here. And yeah we are aware of Paypal too, I think it always comes with Magento. Thanks!